# How to decrease score of rows which contains extra words

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I'm using MySQL boolean fulltext search, and would like to decrease score of rows which have some extra words compared to my search pattern.

E.g `foo bar` would return `foo bar` and `bar foo` with a higher score than `foo baz bar`

Comment: Your explainment is a bit crypto... See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: But i assume you meant in cases like [these](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8HfE9YRwGNKHGi1rUzxcfw/2) the search `'+foo +bar'` on `'foo bar'`  should have a higher (100%) matching score instead of the one shown?